# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar valores duplicados en columnas diferentes de dataframe de R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Me gustaría crear un dataframe que **elimine los valores repetidos en función de las columnas**.

Adjunto un ejemplo en el que querría seleccionar las valores de C1 que no se repiten en C3 ni C4 y conservar toda la fila. De tal manera que:

- La fila 1 se elimina porque aparece "a" en la fila 3 de C3.
- La fila 2 se elimina porque aparece "b" en la fila 1 de C3.
- La fila 3 no se elimina porque no aparece "c" en C3 ni C4.
- La fila 4 se elimina porque aparece "d" en las fila 2 y 3 de C4.
- La fila 5 no se elimina porque no aparece "e" en C3 ni C4.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
df <- data.frame(
  "C1" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
  "C2" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 7.8),
  "C3" = c("b", "b", "a", "d", "f"),
  "C4" = c("a","d","d","a", "g")) 


##   C1  C2 C3 C4
## 1  a 1.2  b  a
## 2  b 3.4  b  d
## 3  c 4.5  a  d
## 4  d 5.6  d  a
## 5  e 7.8  f  g

df_final <- data.frame(
  "C1" = c("c", "e"),
  "C2" = c(4.5, 7.8),
  "C3" = c("a", "f"),
  "c4" = c("f", "g"))

##   C1  C2 C3 c4
## 1  c 4.5  a  f
## 2  e 7.8  f  g
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el operador `%in%` (`match`) en R-base junto con la función 'extract' `[`.

Primero, puedes crear un vector con los valores de la columna `C1` que están en las otras dos columnas:

```
lineas = df$C1 %in% df$C4 |df$C1 %in% df$C3
```

```
> lineas
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Luego, se puede seleccionar las líneas de la tabla que no cumplen la condición usando el operador `!`

```
> df[!lineas, ]
  C1  C2 C3 C4
3  c 4.5  a  d
5  e 7.8  f  g
```

Otra opción es usar un abordaje similar con el operador `%chin%` (`chmatch`) en el paquete `data.table`. El operador está diseñado para trabajar con caracteres.

```
library(data.table)

dt = setDT(df)# convertir la tabla a "data.table"
```

```
> dt[ !C1 %chin% C3 & !C1 %chin% C4]
   C1  C2 C3 C4
1:  c 4.5  a  d
2:  e 7.8  f  g
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es eliminar las filas dónde el valor de C1 se repite en otras filas, pero no en la misma, esto se puede implementar fácilmente con un ciclo y validar la existencia de cada valor de C1 con los de las otras columnas eliminando la fila actual:

```
borrar <- integer()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (!any(df$C1[i] %in% cbind(df$C3[-i], df$C4[-i]))) {
    borrar <- c(borrar, i)
  }
}

df[borrar, ]

  C1  C2 C3 C4
3  c 4.5  a  d
5  e 7.8  f  g
```